# Android map API earlier working key suddenly stopped working

Tags: android, dictionary, api-key

I have used maps before in a small app and it was working fine and i wanted to use it again in another #android app using google API 2.1 update api level 7 emulator. The problem is that getFromLocationName() function is not working. The returned size of list is zero. After many hours, I used my friend's computer registered MAP API key. Then getFromLocationName is working but showing no tiles. I gave code to him and asked him to use his API key and same emulator and IT WORKED. I have checked my md5 has key again and checked generated key also. I tried to reopen previous working app and it is also not working now. I have also tried to use new emulator nothing works. Damn frustrated please help..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried signing the application with a release key (and corresponding api key ofc), and then validate it on the emulator?

It can give a good indication whether or not there's something wrong with your debug keystore.

Comment: Nope I dnt knw how to do that. But I changed my debug keystore and took it from my friend. Now I am using it and it works fine.